# heroku moonshado defunct?

Tags: heroku

Within the last 2 weeks, Moonshado has ceased functioning for my app.

1. error is: "Account getaddrinfo: Name or service not known"
2. heroku dashboard shows my moonshado addin is "deprecated" .. what does that mean? I haven't received any information about that and I am still being charged for the addin.
3. clicking the moonshado link on my heroku dashboard page fails with error: "The server at heroku.moonshado.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. "
4. `$  curl http://<API KEY>@heroku.moonshado.com

   curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'heroku.moonshado.com'

   $ nslookup heroku.moonshado.com

   ** server can't find heroku.moonshado.com.gateway.xxxxx.net: REFUSED`
5. phone call to Moonshado contact number  (800) 971-3106 hangs up after 3 rings.

Comment: Same thing happening to me.  How did you resolve the charges, @user96009?  I'm going to reach out to Heroku to see what the story is and how I can get this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Moonshado seems to be unresponsive - their website seems only half functional, and they've been removed from the add ons catalog: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moonshadosms

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my Moonshado using Heroku app stopped working recently and contacted Heroku support who just told me:

> Hey Ben,
>
> Moonshado stopped working a few hours into February. You'll find on
>   your Feb invoice that we switched you to the free plan effective the
>   1st of the month so that you incurred no further charges, and in March
>   we deprovisioned the add-on entirely.
>
> Best,
>
> G

Hopefully Heroku will arrange an sms add-on with some other provider.